# Finding list of fonts for each PC

Tags: sccm, vbscript, query, font

I am trying to find the best way to find a list of clearview fonts on each PC on our domain. Questions:

1.) Should I use SCCM & how? I've create a Query but I am getting nothing right now. I was told that SCCM does not inventory fonts. I created a inventory for fonts and still nothing.

2.) Should I use a script and deploy it to find the clearview fonts of %windir%/Fonts?

Comment: The fonts are listed in the registry as well under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your client settings and create a new client for software inventory and turn it on looking for the font extension you are wanted to report on.

I would suggest making a small group to apply those settings to first to see if that scan impacts their usage as it could be hefty.

Then you can find the devices using reporting "Software - Files".

You can also then create a collection with a query looking for the font extension you are searching for.

Some helpful links

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh509028.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/gg682067.aspx#BKMK_SoftInventoryDeviceSettings